# How to remove characters from timestamps in a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I am trying to remove the brackets and apostrophes from a dataframe in pandas, so that I can further parse the timestamp, which is in this format: YYYY/MM/DD:HH:MM:SS.

The code I'm using looks like this:

```
finallog = newerlog.split()
ts = finallog[0::6]
ip = finallog[1::6]
proxy = finallog[3::6]
refurl = finallog[4::6]
requrl = finallog[5::6]
```

An example of an erroneous timestamp at the beginning of the dataframe is: ['2020/11/13:02:16:43
There are others in the dataframe that have an apostrophe, such as '2020/11/14:10:14:16
Of course, the final element has the closing inverse as the beginning example ']

Any advice on how to remove these? The timestamps need to be uniform length if I am to slice them further.

Comment: could you show like 10 rows of the df and how those errors look>

Comment: how about stripping all non digits and just parsing the dates like that? YYYYMMDDHHMMSS?

Answer (score 1):

if you know all the erroneous characters already:

```
element = '["2020/11/13:02:16:43'
clean_element = element.replace('[', '').replace('"', '').replace("'", '').replace(']', '')

>> '2020/11/13:02:16:43'
```

Comment: The data frame is pretty simple and looks like this:                                df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Timestamps": clean_ts,
        "IP": ip,
        "ReferringURL": refurl,
        "RequestedURL": requrl})

Comment: These are excellent suggestions. I'm trying them now.